# Decide which object comes first in code

Tags: jquery

Quick JQuery-question: How can one decide which of two objects comes first in a code?

Edit: I want to do something like this.

```
var active = $("#second");
if(active is before $("#first")) ...
else ...
```

Ex:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td id="first">  </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
<td id="second"> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using jQuery 1.4+, `.add()` will do the trick.

> As of jQuery 1.4 the results from
>   .add() will always be returned in
>   document order (rather than a simple
>   concatenation).

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/add/

You can write a simple plugin for this:

```
$.fn.isBefore = function (selector) {
    return this.add(selector)[0] == this[0];
};
```

Then use it like so:

```
if (active.isBefore("#first")) {...}
// "#first" can really be replaced with any valid expression that can be used
// by $().
```

Comment: Not exactly what I mean.
I have saved one of the objects in a variable, and want to check it against the one that is active.

var active = $("#second");
Does the object stored in active come before or after $(this)? That is what I want to find out :)

Comment: @Øyvind, what do you mean then? I've updated my code to look more like yours, and I'm really not seeing the difference. I think we may have just been out of sync with all the editing :P

Answer (score 1):

Use the first selector

```
$('table td:first');
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't sort out the problem. Box9s did. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$('table td').eq(0);
```